# How can I bring fire when a waterfall is in the way?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

During my playthrough I came across a cave which had a waterfall blocking the only entrance. The cave had a burnable basket (containing resources), but since my only way to carry fire is via torch, and the waterfall automatically puts it out, I couldn't get the resources.

Am I missing a skill which allows you to carry fire some other way than a torch or through waterfalls and should come back later when I have it, or should there some other method to bring fire to the cave via torch and should I explore other ways to enter it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need to explore further, you are missing the equipment that allows you to ignite the torch by yourself without an external ignition source.

You pick up this piece of equipment in the Cliffside village area right before you return to the Mountain Village after the next section of the game, you will be able to return and get the precious resources then.